# How to make a list component slide down after a dropdown menu is triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a list with two buttons, and each button have the same dropdown content in a sidebar component. The problem is that when I click on a button to trigger the dropdown list, the second button doesn't move down. How can I make the second button slide down after the dropdown content is opened?

Here is what I've done so far:

**MenuBarGame.js**

```
     import React , {useState} from 'react'
     import css from '../components/css/MenuBarGame.css'
     import Logo from '../logo.png'

     function MenuBarGame(props){
      const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

     function handleDropdown() {
       if(click == false){
       setClick(true); 
       }
       else{
       setClick(false)
    }
  }

return(
    <>
    <div>
            <li>
                 <button className="gameButton" onClick={handleDropdown}><img src={Logo}/> {props.data.name}</button>
                 {click?
                 <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <button>* Duel</button>
                    <button>* Events</button>
                    <button>* Leaderboard</button>
                 </div>:null}
            </li> 
    </div>

    </>
)

}
export default MenuBarGame
```

**MenuBarGame.css**

```
.MenuBarGame{ 
margin-top: 10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
color: white;
}

.MenuBarGame ul{ /*Oyun tablerinin içinde olduğu alanın özellikleri*/
padding: 0px 1.5em 0px 1.5em;
height: 15px;
}

.MenuBarGame ul li { /*Oyunların birbirlerine göre özellikleri*/
display:flex;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.MenuBarGame ul li img { /*Resimlerin cssi*/
border: 1px solid #0ab74c;
border-radius: 100%;
width:2em;
height:2em;
margin-right: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.gameButton { /*Oyun butonlarının özellikleri*/
color: white;
border: 1px solid transparent;
height: fit-content;
width: 150px;
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #1c3527;
position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: flex;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 60px; 
width: 100%;   
background-color:#343438;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.dropdown-content  a{
display: flex;
color: white;
padding: 16px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-content button {
text-align: left;
margin-left: 15px;
}


.dropdown-content a:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

What I've done in the dashboard component:

**Dashboard.js**

```
 <div className="MenuBarGame">
        <ul>
          <MenuBarGame data={{name:"Game1"}}></MenuBarGame>
          <MenuBarGame data={{name:"Game2"}}></MenuBarGame>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your request, you need to copy paste the following code into your MenuBarGame.js (Don't forget to import `useRef` and `useEffect`):

```
function MenuBarGame(props) {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const dropdown = useRef();
  const btn = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (click)
      btn.current.style.marginBottom = `${dropdown.current.offsetHeight}px`;
    else btn.current.style.marginBottom = 0;
  }, [click]);

  function handleDropdown() {
    setClick(!click);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <li>
          <button className="gameButton" onClick={handleDropdown} ref={btn}>
            <img src={Logo} /> {props.data.name}
          </button>
          {click ? (
            <div className="dropdown-content" ref={dropdown}>
              <button>* Duel</button>
              <button>* Events</button>
              <button>* Leaderboard</button>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </li>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default MenuBarGame;
```

[Here is a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/menubargame-xydy4?file=/src/MenuBarGame.js:92-954) in codesandbox.

The reason that the second button covered the first dropdown was because you set `position: absolute` on dropdown content. That makes the elements below it ignore its height and overlap on it. In my solution, I set bottom margin on the first button, and the value of that depends on the first dropdown's height.

Comment: I edited my code as you wrote, but now the first button's dropdown list is behind the second button(the second button overlays the dropdown list). I want the second one to slide down to make room for the dropdown list.

Comment: @mertm I have edited my answer according to your requirements.